# $\lim\limits_{R \rightarrow \infty}{|\cos z|}$ in complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, limits, trigonometry

Let $z=Re^{i \alpha}$ $\alpha$ is given number and $\alpha \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

Find (if exist)
$\lim\limits_{R \rightarrow \infty}{|\cos z|}$

What happen if function $f(z)=|\cos z|$ when $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$?

I have no idea how to do it. Any ideas? I will be so grateful.

Comment: Can you write $\cos z$ in another form, using $z= R\cos\alpha + iR\sin\alpha$ for example?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\cos(x+iy)=\cos(x)\cosh(y)-i\sin(x)\sinh(y)
$$
In your example, $Re^{i\alpha}=R\cos(\alpha)+iR\sin(\alpha)$, therefore,
$$
\cos(Re^{i\alpha})=\cos(R\cos(\alpha))\cosh(R\sin(\alpha))-i\sin(R\cos(\alpha))\sinh(R\sin(\alpha))
$$
If $\sin(\alpha)\ne0$, as $R\to\infty$, $\cosh(R\sin(\alpha))\sim|\sinh(R\sin(\alpha))|\sim\frac12e^{R\,|\!\sin(\alpha)|}$.

Therefore, if $\sin(\alpha)\ne0$, as $R\to\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\cos(Re^{i\alpha})\right|
&\sim\frac12\left|e^{iR\cos(\alpha)}\right|e^{R\,|\!\sin(\alpha)|}\\
&=\frac12e^{R\,|\!\sin(\alpha)|}\\
\end{align}
$$
and so
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty}\left|\cos(Re^{i\alpha})\right|=\infty
$$
However, if $\sin(\alpha)=0$, then as $R\to\infty$,
$$
\left|\cos(Re^{i\alpha})\right|=|\cos(R)|
$$
and so
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty}\left|\cos(Re^{i\alpha})\right|\text{ does not exist}
$$